# facing an error in chef when trying to run the code

Tags: chef-infra

```
[root@ip-172-31-12-214 cookbook]# chef-client -z --runlist "recipe[abc::recipe1]"

[2023-11-23T06:08:13+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line. Using command line options instead.

[2023-11-23T06:08:13+00:00] WARN: No cookbooks directory found at or above current directory.  Assuming /home/ec2-user/cookbook.
Starting Chef Infra Client, version 15.0.300
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["abc::recipe1"]

================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: abc

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* abc::recipe1

System Info:
------------
chef_version=15.0.300

platform=amazon

platform_version=2023

ruby=ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]


program_name=/usr/bin/chef-client

executable=/opt/chef-workstation/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2023-11-23T06:08:15+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers

Running handlers complete
[2023-11-23T06:08:15+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete

Chef Infra Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds

[2023-11-23T06:08:15+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out

[2023-11-23T06:08:15+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report

[2023-11-23T06:08:15+00:00] FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: 412 "Precondition Failed"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a warning in your stacktrace:

```
WARN: No cookbooks directory found at or above current directory.  Assuming /home/ec2-user/cookbook.
```

It look like the cookbook "abc" is not present `/home/ec2-user/cookbook`

You need to ensure the cookbook is located in your cookbook path